# SUM quantity by date if name matches

Tags: mysql

How can I SUM by date certain value if the name matches the same way `stripos($tocheck, "V2")` does?

SUM all the `"name"` by date if contains text - "V2", if this is not clear please ask, I really don't know how to explain but I'll try to give more information if there's need of.

This currently takes all the data and SUMs it by day

```
$sql_download = "SELECT date, name, SUM(quantity) FROM downloads GROUP BY DATE(`Date`)";



`downloads` (`id`, `date`, `name`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1, '2015-05-13 23:30:09', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
(2, '2015-05-13 23:30:09', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(3, '2015-05-14 00:30:09', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
(4, '2015-05-14 00:30:09', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(5, '2015-05-14 07:05:07', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
(6, '2015-05-14 07:10:07', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
(7, '2015-05-14 12:05:00', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(8, '2015-05-14 15:00:00', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(9, '2015-05-14 17:10:06', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(10, '2015-05-14 20:15:06', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(11, '2015-05-14 21:50:06', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
(12, '2015-05-14 21:50:06', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(13, '2015-05-15 12:00:07', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
(14, '2015-05-15 21:55:42', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(15, '2015-05-15 23:47:07', 'CRCPV2-01 - Cartoon Race Cars Pack V2 - 01', 1),
(16, '2015-05-16 03:31:06', 'CRCP03 - Cartoon Race Car Pack 03', 1),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `WHERE` condition to check if `name` matches:

```
  SELECT date, name, SUM(quantity)
    FROM downloads
   WHERE name LIKE '%V2%'
GROUP BY DATE(`Date`)
```